# Migrating TFS to GitHub - how to preserve users?

Tags: git, github, tfs

I'm doing a test run of migrating TFS to Github.  I used [git-tfs](http://git-tfs.com/) to migrate the repository and all is well.  Now, I want to get my users to move across to GitHub, and I still want to keep their historical TFS checkins linked to their new/existing GitHub logins.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, this turns out to be pretty easy... it's handled on the GitHub website.  Once you're signed in to GitHub, you can claim any unassigned users as below (imagining for a minute that I'm Rachel):

[image]

Comment: This is the problem with git on any platform other than TFS  no auditability as users can claim to be anyone they like... Security out the window...

Comment: @MrHinsh not true; if you want to claim an address, you have to verify that you own that address.  The Git-Tfs import preserved the emails of all the TFS users; when the Git users want to claim those addresses, they have to get an authentication code sent to their email.

Comment: That might be a feature of Github but it is not a feature of Git. However I can claim to be anyone I like as long as I setup my own identity with an email. I can't do that with TFS or VSO connected to Active Directory. That is owned by my organisation and is traceable.

Comment: @MrHinsh Fair distinction... but anyway, if you're working as part of a team you need to have a central repository somewhere.  Whether that's GitHub or something internal, you should choose a solution that requires authentication... unless you don't care, in which case, it doesn't matter.